# Escape / in .split()

Tags: javascript, regex, split

Need to escape `/` in javascript `.split()` function but cannot seem to figure out!

```
input -> string "07777/25555,00255" or any of 0777/2555 0777,2555

output -> array {07777,25555,00255}

var p = item.gdp.split(/ , | \//);
```

Not really good with regex!

Comment: `\/` is the correct way to escape `/`, but what are you trying to split exactly?

Comment: Are you saying that you want the result of `0777/2555 0777,2555` to be `["0777", "25555", "00255"]` ?  That will take more than a split, if you're coalescing the common part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this does is split on either `" , "` or `" /"` (note the space characters: *space* comma *space* and *space* forward slash). Your regular expression is absolutely fine if that's what you're intending to replace on.

Here's a Regexper visualisation:

[image: Example]

---

#### Update

There are no spaces in your string at all, so you need to remove those:

```
item.gdp.split(/,|\//);
```

With this, your result will be:

```
["07777", "25555", "00255"]
```

---

A more practical regular expression to use though would be `/[,\/]` - the square brackets will match on any character held within them.

Comment: You don't need the `g` global for a split - it will already split on each occurrence of the given pattern.

Comment: @FabrizioMazzoni are you sure `item.gdp` contains `"07777/25555,00255"`?

Comment: What tool is this (visualize)?

Answer (score 2):

```js
var item={gdp:"07777/25555,00255"};
var p = item.gdp.split(/[,/]/);
document.write(p[0] + "<br>" + p[1] + "<br>" + p[2]);
```

07777

25555

00255

Comment: Can you include the regex delimiter in its body without escaping it?

Comment: That's new to me. Unusual code parsing rules. Its like `var p = "hello";world";`

Comment: Yea, i guess its the opening `[` who let javascript expect a closing `]`.

Comment: Don't guess. Know.  Characters within a character class lose their special meaning (except predefined character classes themself. see my answer). That is pretty common, not just in JS

Comment: @StephenP - Oh yeah? Let me tell you how unusual. Which comes first, the character class or the regex delimiter?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one

```
split(/\s*[,\/]\s*|\s+/);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are splitting on only comma and slash as in your first string
`"07777/25555,00255"`
you can simply split on the character class containing those two characters `[,/]`
Within a character class the slash does not need to be escaped, so the resulting statement would be
`var p = item.gdp.split(/[,/]/);`

If you also want to split on space, as in your other example `0777/2555 0777,2555` simply add space to the character class:
`var p = item.gdp.split(/[, /]/);`

or to split on any whitespace (space, tab, etc.) use the predefined `\s`:
`var p = item.gdp.split(/[,\s/]/);`

Further, you can collapse multiple whitespace, but then you need to go beyond a simple character class. Compare...

```
var str="07777/25555,00255     0777,3444";

// split on white, comma, or slash. multiple spaces causes multiple results
str.split(/[\s,/]/)
// -> ["07777", "25555", "00255", "", "", "", "", "0777", "3444"]

// split on multiple whitespace, OR on comma or slash
str.split(/\s+|[,/]/)
// -> ["07777", "25555", "00255", "0777", "3444"]
```

Comment: The last regex is not quite right. Because of the alternation precedence, `"assdf /asdf"` will be split into three.

Comment: @sln That is true, but `"assdf,/asdf"` will also do that.  I only even mentioned collapsing whitespace because it comes up more often.  If you have something like `"qwer,,zcxv"` it's pretty likely that you _want_ the empty field #2 to be represented in the result, while `"qwer     asfd     zxcv"` is more likely to be 3 fields separated by multiple spaces-and/or-tabs.

Comment: Yeah, its an odd case. I do think though, that a stand alone whitespaces would qualify as a hard delimiter, while within an adjacent sequence its soft, consumed as part of a single [`,/]` Just my analysis if I were doing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
input.split(/[\/\s,]+/)
```

Is this what you are looking for?